# cursor is always null even many records are inserted successfully

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am writing a simple crud operation in using **sqlite** database. When i press insert  button the data is inserted successfully. But when I press the search button, cursor always appears empty and cursor count always is 0. I am giving my code .Please see specifically the code under `btnSearch.setOnclickListener` and `btnInsert.setOnclickListener`

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_db2);
    btnInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

    edname = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edphone = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    edaddress = findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Info(Name Varchar, phone Varchar, address Varchar)");


    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Cursor cursor=null;
            try {if(cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    Toast.makeText(DB.this, "button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int count = cursor.getCount();
                    Toast.makeText(DB.this, String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(DB.this, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(DB.this, "cursor is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(DB.this, "ERROR: "+ ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
           }
    });

    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = edname.getText().toString();
            String phn = edphone.getText().toString();
            String addr = edaddress.getText().toString();
            String query = "INSERT INTO Info (Name,phone,address)VALUES("+name+","+phn+","+addr+")";
            Toast.makeText(DB.this, "data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try This: To insert data into Info Table      

  btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = edname.getText().toString();
                String phn = edphone.getText().toString();
                String addr = edaddress.getText().toString();
                insertData(name,addr,phn);

            }
        }); 


    public void insertData(String name, String address, String phoneNumber) {
                SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put("Name", name);
                    contentValues.put("phone", address);
                    contentValues.put("address", phoneNumber);
                    database.insert("Info", null, contentValues);

            }
```

Comment: sree! I have made another post at stackoverflow. this is the link: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333701/facebook-page-in-web-view-reloads-when-orientation-changes?noredirect=1#comment87683996_50333701               Please read it and guide me if you can , I will be thankful to you

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have a `Database` class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and please write all your your queries for creating table in it.

Now you are initializing `cursor` as `cursor = null`, this will always return `null` values.

Try to use

```
Cursor lCursor = null;

try {
    SQLiteDatabase lDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    lCursor = lDataBase.rawQuery(pQuery, null);  // pQuery = you query for search

    if (lCursor != null && lCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(DB.this, "button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        Toast.makeText(DB.this, String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(DB.this, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(DB.this, "cursor is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Do something when exception occurs
}
```

One more thing: your data is not getting stored in database. Because you are not executing your query. Use this

```
btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = edname.getText().toString();
            String phn = edphone.getText().toString();
            String addr = edaddress.getText().toString();
            String query = "INSERT INTO Info (Name,phone,address)VALUES("+name+","+phn+","+addr+")";
            db.execSQL(query);
            Toast.makeText(DB.this, "data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, you need to apply some common object-oriented programming principles like **[Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)**.

You need to isolate your **Data Base** to not know anything about the Business Rules of your app. This is a good [starting point](https://fernandocejas.com/2018/05/07/architecting-android-reloaded/).

**About your problem:**

- Your not implementing SQLite properly. SQLite needs to extend a helper class to create, update, and delete the DB when require. Check this [article](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) to get you started.

**Extra:** `btnInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);` Casting is no longer require in Android Studio 3 + so remove the Cast to leave it much simpler = `btnInsert = findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);`