# save the state of web page in web-view when screen orientation changes

Tags: android, http

Hi I am loading a Facebook page in web-view. The problem is that when i load URL in web-view, the page opens successfully but the page always reloaded when the orientation changes.

This problem only occurs for URLs of Facebook pages(e.g. Facebook.com/Mobile Covers).

But if i load URL as Facebook.com  or YouTube.com or any other website or its specific web page , page does not reloads when orientation of screen changes.

Similar thing I want in the case of specific Facebook page (i-e page should not reload when the screen orientation changes).

So please guide me about How can I prevent reloading of Facebook page in web-view when orientation changes?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46849736/4255978

Comment: I have tried your provided link and implemented all the things given in that link, but all in vain. I am again emphasizes that reloading is happening only in the case of facebook page